# Customizing Chrome Inspektor's margin and padding colors

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to change my browser from firefox to chrome, but the biggest problem is the colors of the paddings and margins when I hover an element to inspect. There is no such difference between colors like it is in Firefox. (margin:yellow, padding: purple, element itself: blue). I want to customize the Chrome's dev tools. I customized almost everything in the Custom.css folder, but I don't know what element to style for these colors. I read that there is somewhere devTools.css file, and in it I can find the style and change it, but I couldn't find that file, and I think I would not find the element either. I am using Windows XP.

So please If someone knows, tell me what to do ... how can I change the colors ?

edit:

I have read some articles and I finaly found this.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37768

If I am not wrong that's related to my question. I see the people are talking about that and that and there is a "patch"

```
Created an attachment (id=104186) [details]
[PATCH] Altered hover backgrounds for the Metrics pane sections to follow the new highlight
created.
```

But I don't know if I can change my colors with this patch. Actually I don't know can I run this patche somehow and then use it to change my colors.

If someone have clue what is this and can I use it to solve my problem please share your opinion :)